# The select() system call isn't working as expected

Tags: c, unix, network-programming, system-calls

I am using select system to wait for input.Also i am doing this in a loop.
Here is the code.

```
int main()
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;  

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0,&rfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        select(1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
        if(FD_ISSET(0,&rfds))
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"yes",3);
            FD_CLR(0,&rfds);    
        }

        tv.tv_sec = 5;
            tv.tv_usec = 0; 
    }   
    return 0;

}
```

Now the problem is that the select call is working fine only for the first time.If I give input within the first 5 sec I get yes as output but then in the following iterations fd(0) remains unset irrespective of whether I provide any input or not.Any idea how I can solve this problem.

Comment: that's not c++ (more like c)

Comment: @Axalo alright my bad.Can you help me with the problem?

Comment: @Axalo btw that's c++

Comment: You should use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select` (since `poll` is more [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) friendly)

Comment: @cyclops if a c compiler compiles that code without errors it's not c++.

Comment: Where is the input coming from? A socket, a pipe, a tty?

Comment: @Axalo: C++ was designed to be mostly C compatible, and the above code (with suitable `#include`-s) is -on POSIX or Linux systems- both C99 & C++11 compatible.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for the suggestion.I have used poll and it works fine.But I have to implement the problem using select-sytem call.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know that it's compatible but it doesn't make sense to flag it as c++ if it can be interpreted as c.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch standard input

Comment: @Axalo that's c++, the c standard(5.1.2.2.1) requires `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @cyclops: but *stdin* does not means much. If it is a terminal, it is usually *kernel* buffered. Read [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Comment: If you bother to open up *web search engine* and write "linux select" in there, click the first link and read, you would see that `FD_SET() and FD_CLR() respectively add and remove a given file descriptor from a set.` So yes, since you REMOVE the fd from the list you are interested in, you won't get anything from it anymore....

Comment: @Alegnem even if i use FD_SET(0,&rfds) after fd_CLR(0,&rfds) the bit for 0 remains set.As a result the in the next iteration select system call returns 1(i.e 0 is set) without even waiting for input.

Comment: @mch you're right, forgot about that

Comment: BTW, *syscalls are working as documented*. You simply should *read more carefully the documentation*.

Comment: @cyclops And did you read all the data that was waiting to be read in `stdin`? ;)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I read the doc thoroughly and only after that I am here.I tried sever permutations and combinations but none worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

#### Problem one: `select` on empty file descriptor sets

The first is that `select` modifies the file descriptor sets it is given -- after `select` returns, they contain the file descriptors that are ready for I/O. This means that if the timeout passes without any input on stdin, `rfds` will be empty, and the next call to `select` will wait for input on an empty file descriptor set -- where it will never find any.

Input on stdin would keep `STDIN_FILENO` (which is `0`) in the set, but since in the event that it turns up you call

```
FD_CLR(0,&rfds);
```

to remove stdin from the set, `select` will wait on an empty fd set in that case as well. I know why you put that there, though, and it is related to the second problem (see below). The fix for this first problem, in any case, is to put stdin back into the fd set before you call `select` again:

```
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
```

#### Problem two: Input sitting in stdin for ever and ever

The second problem is that while your program waits for input on stdin, it never consumes any. This means that if you fix the file descriptor set before every call to `select` with `FD_SET(0, &rfds);`, your program will end up printing "yes" over and over in an infinite loop.

This is because once input is waiting to be consumed in stdin, calling `select` on that file descriptor will result in `select` checking if there's input waiting, recognizing that yes, there is, telling you about that fact, whereupon you don't do anything with it and just ask `select` to check if it is still there. Which it is, no matter how often you check.

I don't know how exactly you want to consume the input, so this next bit is guesswork. I'm assuming that you want the program to write "yes" if the user entered something. When a user entered something is not always clearly defined, but a common interpretation is to say that user input is typically line-based -- the user expects things to happen once he pressed return. One sane method, then, would be to discard until the next newline when data appeared, so that every press on the return button yields a "yes". That might look like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n'); // discard until end-of-line
```

with `int c;`.

#### Putting it together

In summary, this might do what you want:

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  fd_set rfds;
  struct timeval tv;
  int c;

  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(0,&rfds);

  tv.tv_sec = 5;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    select(1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
    if(FD_ISSET(0, &rfds))
    {
      puts("yes");
      while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'); // consume input
    } else {
      puts("no");
      FD_SET(0, &rfds); // place stdin back in the fd set
    }

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0; 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) . I should have flushed input buffer.

Comment: You cannot flush an input buffer anymore than you can flush a water tap. `fflush` is for output streams. There exists `__fpurge`, but its semantics are not terribly well defined wrt buffering. Stick with the line-based input, it's the most predictable.

Answer (score 1):

On some implementations [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is allowed to modify the file descriptor sets and the timeout. So you should set these inside the loop just before the `select`

```
while(1) {
  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(0,&rfds);
  tv.tv_sec = 5;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;
  int ns = select(1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
  if (ns < 0 && errno == EINTR) continue;
  else if (ns < 0) { perror("select"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You need to keep the result `ns` of `select`, and you need to handle error cases. You probably should inspect `rfds` and `tv` *after* your `select` -when it is successful (`ns>0`)...

As I commented, you should use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select` (since `poll` is more [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) friendly, and since the size of your system's `fd_set` is *compile*-time limiting the highest file descriptor)

Notice that if your *stdin* is a *tty* things are quite complex (since usually *tty*-s are *kernel* buffered, see the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page).

Comment: Unless actually needing to handle thousands of sockets, there's no need to prefer *poll* ovet *select* (other than arguably nicer API of *poll*). And for thousands of sockets, neither is very good, better use eg. *epoll* on Linux, or some multiplatform library which hides the non-portable code.

Answer (score 0):

Once getting a data from stdin the code clears read file descriptor set(rfds) using FD_CLR(0,&rfds) command so in the next loop there your read file descriptor is empty